# Kusto: Adding additional columns from specific data

Tags: performance, processor, azure-data-explorer

With Kusto in Azure Log Analytics I'm trying to accomplish getting an overview of Processor activity for a certain time period. Something like this:

```
Perf 
| where TimeGenerated between ((startofday(now())) .. (endofday(now())))
| where Computer == "servername.domain.local"
| where ObjectName == "Processor Information" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total"
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| render timechart
```

What I would like to add is the data from the processor cores on top of the total processing time and display that in the timechart. I've been messing around for a day now but I can't seem to get it to work. So basically it comes down to doing multiple where statements and putting the results in a separate column (I think)

Can anyone share some insights?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can need to add the column "InstanceName" to the "by" clause of the summarize operator, something like:

```
Perf 
| where TimeGenerated between ((startofday(now())) .. (endofday(now())))
| where Computer == "servername.domain.local"
| where ObjectName == "Processor Information" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), InstanceName
| render timechart
```